# WCF Service with Worker Thread - how to design?

Tags: wcf, worker-thread

I have a WCF Service that serves some clients.
The design is :

- WCF Service Layer
- Business Logic Layer
- Data Access Layer (LINQ-To-Entities)

I need to have a worker thread that does some continuous work on the database (looks for new records, and if finds any - sends information to the client in a 'Push' manner, meaning - the client will be hosting a service so it can receive 'push' notifications from this worker thread).

I will host the WCF service on a windows service.

Question is : Where do I fit this worker thread in my design ?
Should it be spawned in the 'Main()' of the Windows Service's 'Program.cs' along-side the WCF service ? (and this means it should be part of the WCF Service assembly)
Or should it be part of the Business Logic layer - and thus part of the 'Business Logic' assembly ?

What I had in mind:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "client will be hosting a service"? Are you saying that WCF service will have to know about all the clients? Is a Push a requirement? Are you in control of the client(s)?

Comment: I would spawn it at the top most layer, so inside Main()

Comment: The 'Push' is a requirement. when the client connects to the server, it will pass the server it's endpoint configuration, and the server will also connect to the client as a client. That way the server can push information to the clients (CallBack support is no good for me, cause the server cannot initiate his own calls to the client)...

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be part of either assembly? I would host this worker thread in it's own process entirely. Host it in a separate windows service for example.

It can then poll the database and push data to the clients.

**UPDATE**

Your design couples together three distinct kind of operations. First you have the database read operations. Then you have the database update operations. Then you have the database notifications (or events).

Each of these different types of operation requirement should be decoupled from each other. This makes the whole architecture easier to maintain and understand.

For example, by decoupling the read operations you can make a decision about whether to use a service interface at all. Maybe it's possible to allow your clients to connect directly the database using ADO to perform select operations?

At any rate, whether you use a service or not, the update operations should be offlined. There is no good reason to couple together read and write operations. This also allows you to reduce the likelihood of database contention and again keeps everything simple. The client sends asynchronous update commands to the update queue and then the update service updates the database.

This is kind of what I am thinking:

[image]

Comment: Well, here is an image of the idea I had in mind : ["What I Had In Mind"](http://s18.postimage.org/5o9bwg13r/Design_Idea.png) . This worker thread needs to know which clients are connected to the WCF service, so it can connect to them to and send them PUSH messages (each client will host it's own WCF Service too). This way the worker thread can use the Data-Access-Layer of the WCF Service, too, instead of creating its own DAL. Is this wrong ?

Comment: So why not persist the list of client endpoints in the database? Better still, have each client subscribe to updates from the data push service.

Comment: First of all - what tool did you use to make this cool drawing ?? Second of all - I think that the updates from the client need to be immediate, not offline. So I don't want a client to press a button to update some info, them refresh the screen (read) and see that the information was not updated yet. He won't understand why the info is not yet updated (it won't help explaining him that the update is in an offline queue). The client wants to see the info update immediately. I think if I use 'Transaction Scopes' it should prevent any concurrency problems I may have.

Comment: So again - I think I will leave the 'read' & 'write' operations in the same service, with the 'write' operations wrapped in Transaction Scopes (95% of the time the clients will only read data).
Regarding the notifications - are you suggesting that the client connects to one service for 'read+write' and to another service for 'notifications subscriptions' ? I am afraid that the information that the 'notifying service' will send won't be aligned with the 'read+write' that the other service does, that's why I thought they should be in the same service, using locks \ transaction scopes.

Comment: The diagram was done in Balsamiq (http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups). Glad you think it looks cool. It's actually for wireframing but I use it for everything.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by the notifications being "aligned with the 'read+write'"

Comment: What I meant was - won't it be problematic if I have 2 different services sending information to the clients from the same database ?

Comment: I am guessing your concern is over the notifications service "going out of sync" with the data being returned by the other services?

Comment: Isn't that kind of the nature of notifications?